# Why isn't my transistor saturated?

Tags: transistors, npn

Using a [BC546 NPN Transistor](https://www.jaycar.com.au/medias/sys_master/images/9071252930590/ZT2150-dataSheetMain.pdf) to trigger an [SSR](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/INKBIRD-Temperature-Controller-Relay-25-A-SSR-24-380VAC-Accessories-replacement/222480561392) from a [current sensor](https://www.ebay.com/itm/391876645958). Sensor to give 1.5-2.7 V out to drive the transistor. SSR requires >= 3 V and uses up to 10 mA.

I want the transistor to fully trigger the SSR (V>3, I=10mA) when a current flows through the sensor.
With R2 = 470 Ohms and best sensor settings (D0) I can get:

Sensor off: V(CE) = 4.57, D0 = 0.29, V(BE) = 0.29

Sensor on: V(CE) = 2.4, D0 = 1.4, V(BE) = 0.62

Sensor on not connected to transistor has D0 = 2.7V

I'm getting 2.5 V(CE) across my transistor, which should have less than 1 V in saturation according to my reading of the datasheet.

I've attempted R2 = between 400-4000 with the SSR only partially operating.

Here's my schematic:

[image: Schematic]

R1 is a possibility for a constant current circuit, which I don't fully understand (currently shorted/not used).

Comment: Maybe you should attach a schematics of how do you connect things. Just in case...

Comment: Are you sure about those voltages? Are you sure the sensor is capable of providing such current?

Comment: 2.5V Vce and 5V over the SSR adds up to 7.5V. The SSR is specified as 12V 7.5mA. Which by the way is not "compatible with CMOS IC or TTL"

Comment: Power is via USB PSU: 5V  - SSR - (Collector - Emmiter) - 0V. 
Just tried a 47 Ohm base resistor, still no fully powering SSR. 5V powers the SSR nicely. Sensor will output in the range of 2.5V, depending on settings and sense current

Comment: My question was is the sensor capable of providing current you require. Did you measure that voltage under load?

Comment: Sensor off: V(CE) = 4.57, D0 = 0.29, V(BE) = 0.29

Sensor on: V(CE) = 2.4, D0 = 1.4, V(BE) = 0.62

Hmm you be on to something!
- with 56 Ohm resistor

Comment: Something doesn't seem right. But here are a few ideas. Use a FET with a very low Vgs(th) instead of a BJT. Or, use a comparator instead of the BJT. Or use a darlington BJT to avoid overloading the output of your sensor.

Comment: How much hall current do you want to trigger the switch? Recommend using a high resistance divider tied to a MOSFET.

Comment: Provide a proper believable data sheet for the device and not a buyer's link.

Comment: The one piece of information I don't see is actual measured collector current. Even though you say that 3mA should be enough to turn on the SSR, maybe you are way off on that. I think you should add a small collector resistor just so you can see what the collector current is. Maybe try 1 Ohm. If the voltage is exceedingly small across the 1 Ohm (like less than 100 mV) then you can put in 10 Ohms instead. Then calculate Ic.

Comment: Ic came out around 10mA I believe, more than I expected but totally fine if Vsat will be below 1V as in datasheet, still troubleshooting from here

Comment: The new schematic potentially changes everything. What is the value of R1? Basically, you have a voltage follower. The expectation for this circuit is that the emitter will be around 0.6V below the base voltage. Saturation is not expected to occur unless R1 is so small that the transistor reaches saturation without R1 rising to Vb-0.6.

Comment: haven't tried a circuit with R1 as yet..

Comment: So, all the experimental results you have reported are with a different circuit than the one you show, the one with R1? This question is turning into a mess.

Comment: sorry no R1 has not been implemented, yes finding values for a transistor is proving tricky..

Comment: As Chupacabras states in the answer, the sensor can provide up to 2mA. 2mA base current should easily allow 200mA collector current (gain 100) in saturation, which you don't get. Please double-check that you did not confuse collector and emitter terminals of the BC546, because this would perfectly explain the behaviour you are observing (i.e. 10mA out of saturation, a gain of 5).

Answer (score 1):

You are using sensor [WCS1800](http://www.winson.com.tw/Data%20Sheet/WCS1800.pdf) which has maximum current output 2mA. You are exceeding it.

Lower the base current to much lower value, by increasing base resistor.

Comment: Is there an equation I could use for optimal values?
The sensor is supposedly TTL..?

Comment: To the OP: What exactly are you trying to do? I think you should update the original question by editing it and adding an explanation of what the circuit is supposed to do according to you, and what you are using it for. I am afraid it may not work the way you want it to unless what you want is, well, kind of strange.

Comment: done - added details